# Is $tr(B(B^TWB + D)^{-1}B^TW) = tr((I + D(B^TWB)^{-1})^{-1})$?

Tags: self-study, matrix, linear-algebra, eigenvalues

I am reading [Eilers and Marx (1996)](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ss/1038425655) and at the beginning of page 94 they write, for $Q = B^TWB$, $D$ a symmetric positive definite matrix and $W$ a diagonal matrix,

\begin{align}
tr\left(B(Q + D)^{-1}B^TW\right) &= tr\left((I + Q^{-1/2}DQ^{-1/2})^{-1}\right) \\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{1+\epsilon_i}
\end{align}

where $\epsilon_i$ are the eigen values of $Q^{-1/2}DQ^{-1/2}$.

My question is, why don't they write: $tr\left(B(Q + D)^{-1}B^TW\right) = tr\left((I + DQ^{-1})^{-1}\right)$?

Then we could calculate $\epsilon_i$ as the ratio of the eigen values of $D$ by the ones of $Q$, based on [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/573583/eigenvalues-of-the-product-of-2-symmetric-matrices), right?

I appreciate if anyone one point what I am missing here.

Comment: While it doesn't answer the question, I think their $D$ is only positive semidefinite: it's a differencing operator that has $k$ zero eigenvalues for degree-$k$ splines

Comment: Hi @ThomasLumley. I think their $D$ is fact positive semidefinite. The $\mathbf{D}$ I am writting here is what they call $\lambda D^T D$, for $\lambda > 0$, which is positive definite.

Comment: No, it isn't. At the top of p94 they define $Q_\lambda=\lambdaD^TD$, and the second line after equation (24) starts "Because $k$ eigenvalues of $Q_\lambda$are zero..."

Comment: @ThomasLumley, you're definitely right! I made a huge confusion here. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible explanations

1. It's not obvious to me (and might well not even be true) that $D$ and $Q^{-1}$ commute. The linked answer was for the case where $DQ^{-1}$ is symmetric and $DQ^{-1}=Q^{-1}D$ which means that the eigenvalues of the product are products of the eigenvalues. If they don't, you can't get the eigenvalues from those of $D$ and $Q$ that way.
2. It doesn't actually make the next step any easier -- the only fact they need about the $\epsilon_i$ is that $k$ of them are zero.  And when they actually compute $\mathrm{tr}(H)$ in the next section of the paper, they do it by adding up the diagonal elements, which is faster than finding an eigendecomposition.

Comment: Thanks for your time. (1.) I didn't note that they had to commute. My fault. I'll check if they commute. (2.) That makes me think, would building matrix $H = B(B^T W B + D)^{-1}B^T W$ and summing up its diagonal entries still be faster than computing the trace as the ratio of the eigen values of $D$ and $Q$ (in case that is valid)?

Comment: I guess my question wasn't well posed. The main point of my questions is can we write $tr(B(Q+D)^{-1} B^T W)$ as $tr((I + DQ^{-1})^{-1})$ instead of $tr((I + Q^{-1/2} D Q^{-1/2})^{-1})$ for $Q = B^T W B$?